# DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled

Tags: jsf, primefaces, mysql-workbench, eclipse-oxygen

hola buenos dias estoy trabajando con el siguiente xhtml

```
    <h:form id="form_emisor_listado">
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
        <h:outputText id="txt_validador_controlador">
            <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{ctrAdmTipoCuentaListado.inicioValidacionMenu('adm_tipo_cuenta_listado')}" />
        </h:outputText>


        <dc:toolbar controlador="#{ctrAdmTipoCuentaListado}"
            usuarioCrea="#{ctrAdmTipoCuentaListado.objTipoCuentaSeleccionado.usuarioCrea}"
            fechaCrea="#{ctrAdmTipoCuentaListado.objTipoCuentaSeleccionado.fechaCrea}"
            fechaModifica="#{ctrAdmTipoCuentaListado.objTipoCuentaSeleccionado.fechaModifica}"
            usuarioModifica="#{ctrAdmTipoCuentaListado.objTipoCuentaSeleccionado.usuarioModifica}"
            nombreObjetosActualizar="form_emisor_listado:messages"
            verEliminar="false" verImprimir="false" />


        <p:dataTable id="dt_emisor" var="TipoCuenta"
            value="#{ctrAdmTipoCuentaListado.lstTiposCuenta}"
            emptyMessage="No se encuentra registros" paginator="true"
            rows="#{msg.varNumeroPaginacionesInicial}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="#{msg.varNumeroPaginaciones}"
            paginatorPosition="bottom"
            paginatorTemplate=" {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            selection="#{ctrAdmTipoCuentaListado.objTipoCuentaSeleccionado}"
            filteredValue="#{ctrAdmTipoCuentaListado.lstTiposCuentaFiltro}"
            selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{ctc.idTipoCuenta}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Listado Tipo Cuenta
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Id" style="width:32px;text-align: center">
                <h:outputText value="#{TipoCuenta.idTipoCuenta}" />
            </p:column>


            <p:column headerText="Nombre" style="width:32px;text-align: center">
                <h:outputText value="#{TipoCuenta.nombre}" />

            </p:column>






        </p:dataTable>



    </h:form>





</ui:define>
```

Comment: Cual es tu error o problema?

Comment: bueno el problema es que no compila el crud como tal, cuando voy a ingresar un nuevo registro nombre de establecimiento comercial le doy guardar y al momento sale el error de datamodel

Comment: Caused by: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/adm_tipo_cuenta_listado.xhtml - No se pudo restablecer la vista /adm_tipo_cuenta_listado.xhtml.
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:212)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
 ... 27 more

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y mostrar el código del mangedBean donde muestra la información del nuevo registro

Answer (score 0):

Este problema da cuando en `web.xml` no se tiene configurado que acepte las paginas .`xhtml`, también te dejo como iniciar el serverl de `Faces`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>        
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```